# My test class doesn't have enough coverage. How can I fix it?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```java
@isTest
public class TSNotesToReferralBatchTest {
    public static List<Account> testDealersList = new List<Account>();
    public static List<TS_Consultant_Note__c> noteUpdateList = new List<TS_Consultant_Note__c>();
    public static List<CAReferralShar__Referral__c> testreferrallist = new List<CAReferralShar__Referral__c>(); 
    public static List<TradeShow__c> tradeShowObjList = new List<TradeShow__c>(); 
    public static List<TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__c> testBoothConsultant = new List<TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__c>();
    
    @TestSetup  
    
    public static void setupData() {
            
        Account DealerAcct = new Account(Name = 'Test Account ' + DateTime.now().getTime(),
            Cox_Auto_Id__c = '111' + String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()));       
        Id acctIds = DealerAcct.Id;
        testDealersList.add(DealerAcct);
        
        List<Contact> contactList = PRFT_Testdata.createTestcontacts(2, testDealersList);
        insert contactList;   

        Campaign testCampaign = new Campaign (Name = 'TEST SHOW', 
                                        Type = 'Trade Show', 
                                        Status = 'In Progress', 
                                        StartDate = system.today(), 
                                        EndDate = system.today()+1, 
                                        IsActive = true, 
                                        Description = 'THIS IS A TEST SHOW', 
                                        Trade_Show_Location__c = 'Test City'); 
        insert testCampaign;
        
        List<Business_Unit__c> testBU = PRFT_TestData.createTestBusinessUnit();
        testBU[0].Name = 'Autotrader';
        insert testBU;
        
        TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__c testBoothConsultant = new TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__c(
                        Name = UserInfo.getFirstName() + ' ' + UserInfo.getLastName(),
                        Booth_Consultant_2__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),
                        Business_Unit__c = testBU[0].id,
                        Consultant_Type__c = 'Sales Consultant',
                        Trade_Show__c = testCampaign.id ) ;
        insert testBoothConsultant;
        
        TradeShow__c testTradeshow = new TradeShow__c (Contact_Name__c = contactList[0].Name, 
                                         Dealer_Name__c = testDealersList[0].Name,
                                         Contact__c = contactList[0].id,
                                         Account__c = testDealersList[0].id,
                                         Booth_Checkin__c = true,
                                         Campaign__c = testCampaign.id,
                                         Business_Unit__c = testBU[0].id,
                                         Business_Unit_Name__c = testBU[0].Name, 
                                         Booth_Consultant__c = testBoothConsultant.Id);  
        insert testTradeshow;
             
        TS_Consultant_Note__c testnote = new TS_Consultant_Note__c(
                    Business_Unit__c = testBU[0].id,
                    Campaign_Name__c = testCampaign.Name,
                    Campaign__c = testCampaign.id, 
                    Consultants_Name__c = testBoothConsultant.Name, 
                    Contact__c = contactList[0].id, 
                    //Employee__c = Test_Employees[0].id, 
                    FollowUp_Date__c=date.today(), 
                    Follow_up_Requested__c=true, 
                    Notes__c = 'Today is '+date.today()+' Note ',  
                    Time_of_Visit__c = DateTime.now(),
                    TradeShowInterview__c= testTradeShow.Id,
              Referral_Status__c = 'Ready for Referral Submission');
        insert testnote;
        System.assertNotEquals(testnote.id, null);
        
        CAReferralShar__Referral__c testreferral = new CAReferralShar__Referral__c();
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account__c = testDealersList[0].id;
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Type__c = 'Franchise';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Contact__c = contactList[0].id;
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Lead_Source_Editable__c = 'Tradeshow: ' + 'TEST SHOW';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_City__c = 'Atlanta';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Street__c = 'Peachtree';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_State__c = 'GA';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Postal_Code__c = '30350';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Country__c = 'USA';   
                    //RecordTypeName  = 'Sending',
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Referral_Status__c = 'Created';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Method_of_conversation_w_Client__c = 'Call';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Client_Expectation__c = 'This is a test expecatation';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Role_of_Client_Contact__c = 'CEO';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Rating__c = 'Hot';
                    testreferral.Brand__c = 'Autotrader';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Product_Of_Interest__c = 'VinSolutions - CarWars';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Notes__c = 'Test Notes';
                    testreferral.CAReferralShar__Receiving_BU__c = 'Autotrader';

        insert testreferral;
        
    }
    
    public static testmethod void batchContactTestUnit() {
        
        Test.startTest();
            Id batchId = Database.executeBatch( new TSNotesToReferralBatch(), 2 );
        
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

```java
global class TSNotesToReferralBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.stateful
{
    global final String query;
    public Boolean chainAnotherbatch = false;
    public Integer recordLimit;
    private final Id lockedRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.CAReferralShar__Referral__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Locked').getRecordTypeId();
    private final Id sendingRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.CAReferralShar__Referral__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sending').getRecordTypeId();
    private final Map<String, Note_to_Referral_Map__c> noteMap = Note_to_Referral_Map__c.getAll();
    List<TS_Consultant_Note__c> noteUpdateList = new List<TS_Consultant_Note__c>();
    
    global TSNotesToReferralBatch()
    {
        if (recordLimit == null)
        {
            recordLimit = 4;
            TradeShowAdmin__c mySetting = TradeShowAdmin__c.getValues('BU Referral Record Limit');
            if (mySetting != null && String.isNotBlank(mySetting.Value__c))
            {
                recordLimit = Integer.valueOf(mySetting.Value__c);
            }
        }
        
        query = 'SELECT Id, (SELECT TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__r.Name FROM TS_Note_Consultants__r), (SELECT Product__r.Name FROM TS_Product_Interest_del__r), (Select Contact_First_Name__c, Contact_Last_Name__c, TradeShow_Record__r.Contact__r.Account.Cox_Auto_Id__c FROM TS_Notes_Tradeshow_Records__r WHERE TradeShow_Record__r.Contact__c != null),Notes__c, Account__c , Business_Unit__c, Business_Unit__r.Name, Contact__r.Name, ' + 
                       'Campaign__r.Name, Account__r.ShippingCity, Account__r.ShippingStreet, Account__r.ShippingState, ' + 
                       'Account__r.ShippingPostalCode, Account__r.ShippingCountry, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedBy.Email, '+
                       'CreatedBy.Phone, Account__r.Franchise__c, TradeShowInterview__c, Additional_Information__c, ' +
                       'TradeShowInterview__r.ScheduledDemo__c, Account__r.Cox_Auto_Id__c, ' + 
                       'Time_of_Visit__c, Follow_up_Requested__c, FollowUp_Date__c, Sales__c, Retention__c, Hot_Lead__c ' +
                  'FROM TS_Consultant_Note__c ' +
                 'WHERE Referral_Status__c  =  \'Ready for Referral Submission\' ' +
                 'AND TradeShowInterview__r.Contact__c != null ' +
                 'AND TradeShowInterview__r.Account__c != null ' +
                 'LIMIT '+recordLimit;
       System.debug('*** Here is the query '+query);
                 
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
     
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        try
        {
            System.debug('*** Here is scope size '+scope.size() + ' and here is record limit '+recordLimit);
      
            List<CAReferralShar__Referral__c> referrals = new List<CAReferralShar__Referral__c>();  
            noteUpdateList = new List<TS_Consultant_Note__c>();
            
            for (sObject sObj: scope) {
                TS_Consultant_Note__c note = (TS_Consultant_Note__c) sObj;
                CAReferralShar__Referral__c referral = new CAReferralShar__Referral__c();
                Note_to_Referral_Map__c noteObject = noteMap.get(note.Business_Unit__r.Name);
                    
                if (noteObject == null)
                { 
                    note.Referral_Status__c = 'Referral Not Eligible';
                    noteUpdateList.add(note);
                    continue;
                }
                note.Referral_Status__c = 'Referral Successfully Submitted';
                if (note.Account__r.Franchise__c == 'YES') {
                    referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Type__c = 'Franchise';
                } else {
                    referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Type__c = 'Independent';
                }
                referral.Name = note.Contact__r.Name;
                //referral.CAReferralShar__Lead_Source_Editable__c = 'Tradeshow: ' + note.Campaign__r.Name;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Lead_Source_Editable__c = 'Tradeshow: ' + 'OTH - Child - 2022 - Q1 - NADA 2022';
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account__c = note.Account__c;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_City__c = note.Account__r.ShippingCity;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Street__c = note.Account__r.ShippingStreet;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_State__c = note.Account__r.ShippingState;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Postal_Code__c = note.Account__r.ShippingPostalCode;
                referral.CAReferralShar__Account_Shipping_Country__c = note.Account__r.ShippingCountry;   
                referral.CAReferralShar__Rating__c = 'Hot';
                referral.CAReferralShar__Product_Of_Interest__c =noteObject.value__c; 
                referral.CAReferralShar__Contact__c = note.Contact__c;
                referral.RecordTypeId  = sendingRecordTypeId; //Sending
                referral.CAReferralShar__Referral_Status__c = 'Created';

                String boothConsultants = '';
                //append booth consultant info
                Integer consultantCount = 1;
                for(TS_Note_Consultant__c noteConsultant : note.TS_Note_Consultants__r){
                    boothConsultants += noteConsultant.TS_BU_Booth_Consultant__r.Name;
                    if(consultantCount < note.TS_Note_Consultants__r.size()){
                        boothConsultants += ', ';
                    }
                    consultantCount ++;
                }

                //get tradeshow records on note and associated CAIDS -- if only 1 tradeshow record on note, don't show this field
                String tradeshowRecGroupInfo = '';
                Integer tradeshowRecCount = 1;
                for(TS_Note_Tradeshow_Record__c tsNoteTradeshow : note.TS_Notes_Tradeshow_Records__r){
                    tradeshowRecGroupInfo += tsNoteTradeshow.Contact_First_Name__c + ' ' + tsNoteTradeshow.Contact_Last_Name__c + (String.isNotBlank(tsNoteTradeshow.TradeShow_Record__r.Contact__r.Account.Cox_Auto_Id__c) ? ' - ' + tsNoteTradeshow.TradeShow_Record__r.Contact__r.Account.Cox_Auto_Id__c : '');
                    if(tradeshowRecCount < note.TS_Notes_Tradeshow_Records__r.size()){
                        tradeshowRecGroupInfo += ', ';
                    }
                        //Contact_First_Name__c, Contact_Last_Name__c, TradeShow_Record__r.Contact__r.Account.Cox_Auto_Id__c
                }
                String referralNote = 'Time of Visit: '+    note.Time_of_Visit__c.format() + '| Campaign: ' + note.Campaign__r.Name +
                    ' | Consultants: ' + boothConsultants;

                //if there are associated tradeshow records, then append here
                if(String.isNotBlank(tradeshowRecGroupInfo)){
                    referralNote += ' | Contacts: ' + tradeshowRecGroupInfo;
                }

                referralNote = referralNote + ' | Notes: ';
                
                if (String.isNotBlank(note.Notes__c))
                {
                    referralNote = referralNote + note.Notes__c;
                    
                }
                //add products of interest from the note
                String productInfo = '';
                for(TS_Product_Interest__c prodInt : note.TS_Product_Interest_del__r){
                    productInfo += ' | ' + prodInt.Product__r.Name;
                }
                if (String.isNotBlank(productInfo))
                {
                   referralNote = referralNote + productInfo;
                    
                }
                referralNote = referralNote + ' | Follow Up Requested: ' + note.Follow_up_Requested__c + ' | Follow Up Date: ';
                if (note.FollowUp_Date__c != null)
                {
                    referralNote = referralNote + note.FollowUp_Date__c.format();
                }
                referralNote = referralNote + ' | Additional Info: ';
                if (String.isNotBlank(note.Additional_Information__c))
                {
                    referralNote = referralNote + note.Additional_Information__c;
                }
                referralNote = referralNote + ' | Preset Demo : ' + note.TradeShowInterview__r.ScheduledDemo__c;
                referralNote = referralNote + ' | Sales: ' + note.Sales__c + ' | Retention: ' + note.Retention__c + ' | Hot Lead: ' + note.Hot_Lead__c;
                
                System.debug('*** referralNote '+referralNote);
                referral.CAReferralShar__Notes__c = referralNote;    
                referrals.add(referral);     
                noteUpdateList.add(note);                                     
            }
            if (!referrals.isEmpty())
            {
                System.debug('*** before insert referrals');
                insert referrals;  
                    
                for (CAReferralShar__Referral__c ref: referrals) {
                    System.debug('*** id of referral '+ref.Id);
                    ref.CAReferralShar__Referral_Status__c = 'Submitted';
                    ref.RecordTypeId  = lockedRecordTypeId;  //Locked
                }
                System.debug('*** before update referrals');
                chainAnotherBatch = false;
                if(!test.isRunningTest()) {
                    System.debug('** I am about to update '+referrals);
                    update referrals;
                }
            }
            System.debug('*** before update notes');
            update noteUpdateList;
            System.debug('*** referrals '+referrals);
            System.debug('*** scope size '+scope.size() + ' record limit '+recordLimit);
            if (scope.size() == 0)
            {
                chainAnotherbatch = false;
            }
            else if (scope.size() != recordLimit)
            {
                chainAnotherbatch = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                chainAnotherBatch = true;
               
            }
       } 
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           chainAnotherbatch = false;
           for (TS_Consultant_Note__c errorNote : noteUpdateList)
           {
               errorNote.Referral_Status__c = 'Referral Submission Error';
           }
           update noteUpdateList;
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'kevin.seveur@coxautoinc.com','james.stevenson@coxautoinc.com'};
           mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
           mail.setSubject('Errors occurred during TSNotesToReferral Schedulable process.');
           mail.setSenderDisplayName('Apex error message');
           mail.setPlainTextBody(e.getMessage());
           Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail });
       }     
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        if(!test.isRunningTest() && chainAnotherbatch)
        {
            System.debug('*** about to chain another batch***');
            Database.executeBatch(new TSNotesToReferralBatch());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you specify exactly what issue you are facing while attempting to cover x lines, this question is most likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are not entering some of the code blocks for if-then-else and try-catch statements. To get sufficient coverage, you will need several test methods.

After you run your test, go to dev console to the test tab. Under code coverage, double click the class that you are testing. It will show you which lines lack coverage.